# Insert json api data into mysql rds using lambda on aws

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

i figured out(im a real beginner) how to get data in json format from an API using node.js in an aws lambda function. now i would like some help to insert that data into a sql database that I have on aws.

I tried several thinks that didnt work and top of it, it gotta work with lambda.

```
    //var exports = require('exports')
    var getJSON = require('get-json')
    exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    getJSON('https://oneapi.com/api/?action=get_countries&key=wow', 
   function(error, response){
    console.log(error);
    context.succeed (response);
    });

    };
```

So I get this as a result:

```
  [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "England"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Italy"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Spain"
      }
    ]
```

now im looking for a code snippet that inserts this into my sql database which has a table with column id and name.
im looking for something very simply and straightforward.